# Knockout.js and ScriptSharp - Writable Dependent Observables

Tags: knockout.js, script#

I'm using and really enjoying a wicked combination of knockout.js and Script#

While exploring the power of Dependent Observables, i've come across a need to implement the Writable variation as referred to in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html)

How would you capture this ko function in the Script Sharp import class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a new 'Import Library' Project
and defined the missing pieces.

```
namespace KnockoutApi
{
    [Imported]
    [IgnoreNamespace]
    [ScriptName("ko")]
    public static class Ko
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an observable with a value computed from one or more other values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the observable value.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="options">Options for the dependent observable.</param>
        public static DependentObservable<T> DependentObservable<T>(DependentObservableWritableOptions<T> options)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}


[IgnoreNamespace]
[Imported]
[ScriptName("Object")]
public class DependentObservableWritableOptions<T>
{
    public DependentObservableWritableOptions()
    { }

    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets whether the evaluation should be deferred, i.e. not performed
    //     when the observable is first created.
    [IntrinsicProperty]
    public bool DeferEvaluation { get; set; }

    //  
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the function to compute the value.
    [ScriptName("read")]
    [IntrinsicProperty]
    public Func<T> GetValueFunction { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //  Gets or sets the function to compute the value.
    [ScriptName("write")]
    [IntrinsicProperty]
    public Action<T> SetValueFunction { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the model instance which acts as 'this' in the get value function.
    [IntrinsicProperty]
    [ScriptName("owner")]
    public object Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should contribute this back to the project via the git repository on github. Its likely to help others as well...